# Equivalence of topological compactifications

Tags: general-topology

Why is equivalence of compactifications defined the way it is?

For two compactifications $(Y_1,c_1)$ and $(Y_2,c_2)$ of some space $X$, why isn't the existence of a homeomorphism $f$ between them enough - what's the usefulness of $f(c_1(x))=c_2(x)$ for all $x$ in $X$ ?

Intuitively, I would guess that you want to keep the elements from $X$ in some sort structure, so that you can keep going between respective compactifications, without changing what happens with the elements in $X$ (more precisely, their imbeddings), but that's all very vague and not very convincing.

Explanation/motivation for defining equivalence of compactifications the way it is defined, and an example of it's use, both ideally simple, would be appreciated.

Comment: What are the $c_1$ and $c_2$? Are those the embeddings of the original spaces as a dense subspace of the compact spaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main reason for defining the equivalence this way is to give an order structure not to the points in $X$, but to the different compactifications of $X$. You should start by defining an order on the compactifications by saying that one compactification $(Y_1,c_1)$ is less than or equal to another compactification $(Y_2,c_2)$ if and only if there is a continuous surjection $\phi:Y_2\rightarrow Y_1$ such that $c_2\circ \phi=c_1$. In this case the equivalent compactifications are the ones for which you have a homeomorphism. The reason behind wanting an order to the compactifications is to be able to then use Zorn's Lemma to obtain a maximal element in the family of compactifications of a space $X$, which is also known as the Stone-Čech compactification $\beta X$.

Comment: I think there are also other ways of constructing Stone-Cech compactification though - embedding of all continuous functions into $[0,1]$ for example, and it can be shown that every compactification is equivalent to a quotient space of it. Is the way that uses an order nicer in some way? Also, I though Stone-Cech compactification is the largest, not just maximal, could you explain or prove that?

Comment: What do you mean by 'largest'? It is 'largest' in terms of cardinality, but it is also 'largest' in terms of there being a continuous surjection from $\beta X$ to any other compactification of $X$ such that the triangle commutes.
Also, there are other ways of constructing $\beta X$, but the main point of defining equivalence the way you did is a consequence of the definition of order on the compactifications, which leads naturally to defining $\beta X$ as the maximal element.

Comment: IMO, this is a more elegant proof of the existence of $\beta X$. From your notation, I assume you are following Engelking, in which case you should be looking at Corollary 3.5.10. For a (perhaps) more detailed treatment of this material, please see Chapter 6 of  [these lecture notes](http://tinyurl.com/huqnq83) Engelking seems to put the cart before the horse when first definint the equivalence and then the order; the lecture notes do it the other way around, which seems more natural, imo.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and lecture notes. I meant largest, with respect to the order defined, as far as equivalence classes go. I think this is exactly the Corollary 3.5.10 you've mentioned. Could you explain where it is that Zorn's lemma is used in the approach in the lecture notes/Engelking ? Lastly, where would this approach (defining the order this way) fail, if we removed the need for $c_2\circ \phi=c_1$ ?

Comment: Zorn's Lemma states that if every chain in a partially ordered set $S$ has an upper bound in $S$, then $S$ has a maximal element. Theorem 3.5.9 says that every non-empty family of compactifications of $X$ has a least upper bound. Then, by Zorn's Lemma, Corollary 3.5.10 concludes that there is a largest element in the family of compactifications of $X$.

Comment: As for the approach failing: you use $c_2\circ\phi=c_1$ to define the order, where $\phi$ is surjective. You need the order to find a maximal element. The fact that on equivalent compactifications this is a homeomorphism is actually a corollary of the way you define the order - see Lemma 6.2.7 of the lecture notes: 'Suppose $h_i:X\rightarrow Y_i$ ($i=1,2$) are $T_2$ compactifications of $X$ such that $(Y_1,h_1)\leq(Y_2,h_2)$ and $(Y_2,h_2)\leq(Y_1,h_1)$. Then there exists a homeomorphism $g:Y_2\rightarrow Y_1$ such that $h_1=g\circ h_2$.'

Comment: If every non empty family of compactifications of $X$ has a least upper bound, couldn't I just take the whole set of them and take the upper bound?

Comment: As far as the approach, I meant how would it fail, if we defined the order that way, and defined equivalence in some way that would follow - in this case, equivalence would be, that a continuous surjection would exist both from $Y_1$ to $Y_2$ and back.  But I think I already figured that out - I need the $c_2\circ\phi=c_1$ or whatever it is, because I use it when showing that the largest compactification element of the order defined, has a unique extension for every function to a compact Haussdorf space.

Comment: Yes, you are right about taking suprema - I was overcomplicating things. And about the equivalence - the equivalence you defined in your initial question *is* the equivalence that would follow if we define an order via existence of continuous surjections - this is what the Lemma I cited above says. But I'm happy you see why it is useful to have the Lemma, too. :)

Answer (score 1):

This question is years old but I thought I'd share another point of view about the relevance of having a commutative diagram $f\circ c_1 = c_2$, for people in the future could perhaps find it useful too.

Using your notation, imagine that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are actually supersets of $X$ and assume that $c_i:X\hookrightarrow Y_i$ is the inclusion for $i\in\{1,2\}$. Then the compactifications $(Y_1,c_1)$ and $(Y_2,c_2)$ are equivalent iff there is a homeomorphism $f:Y_1\to Y_2$ such that $f(x)=x$ for all $x\in X$.

This says that $X$ is *embedded in the same way* in both compactifications.

In the general case where $Y_i$ is not necessarily a superset of $X$, the previous notion still makes sense, because the embedding $c_1$ acts essentially as a "generalized inclusion". The main idea of a compactification is to think of a space as if it were compact so that one can take advantage of properties that compact spaces have, so it seems natural to ask when two ways of compactifying a space $X$ end up looking exactly the same from the perspective of $X$.

[David Ullrich's answer in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1799772/homeomorphic-but-not-equivalent-compactifications) is very insightful of the essence of this concept and the interpretation that I tried to provide. In his example, not only are his two compactifications not equivalent $-$ they are not even comparable (w.r.t. the preorder mentioned in Simon_Peterson's answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a homeomorphism $f:Y_1\to Y_2$, then there is another compactification $(Y_2,c_3)$ of $X$ such that $f(c_1(x))=c_3(x)$ for all $x\in X$ (let $c_3=f\circ c_1$). By your version of equivalence (homeomorphism alone),  $(Y_2,c_2)=(Y_2,c_3)$. So we may as well include that extra condition the definition to begin with.

Comment: I think you want $(Y_2,c_2)=(Y_2,c_3)$ in there :) Also, this still doesn't explain why you would care if the diagram commutes (i.e. the condition of compositions of functions being fulfilled).